# How do I make grsync exactly mirror my hard drive over multiple backups?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hdd, rsync

I use grsync to backup my laptop's HDD to an external HDD on about a monthly schedule. The problem is that every time I move a folder to inside another folder on my laptop's HDD, grsync will not delete where the folder originally was when syncing to the external HDD. This results in having 2 copies of the data on the external HDD and I have to manually delete where the folder/file originally was.

What flag should I enable in the grsync's menu to make sure that grsync will exactly clone my /home partition and delete any extra files from the external HDD every time I do a full backup run? Just for this I would prefer using grsync than using an rsync command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "delete on destination" checkbox in the "basic options" tab. It's like specifying the `-d` option in rsync which will delete files and folders that are not on the source disk.

Comment: Does the -d flag delete files on destination which are not present in the same folder or the entire drive?

Comment: When you use rsinc or grsync you specify a source and a destination. All actions are limited to these. If the destination is the root of a hard drive, it will effect the whole drive. If the destination is sub folder, it will effect only the sub folder. rsync never goes outside of where you tell it to.

Comment: Just be careful not to use `--remove-source-files` in conjunction with it like I accidentally did (due to shell key bindings). Recovering from such a situation is messy and you might lose files.